# Cannot connect to MySql in Docker. Access Denied Error thrown. Flask-SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, docker, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, docker-compose

Alright so been trying for a while to get this to work. Here is the line of commands I run from start to finish and I get an `Access denied...` error shown below.

```
$ docker-compose up --build -d
$ docker exec -it flaskdocker_mysql_1 mysql -u root -p
mysql> CREATE DATABASE flask_docker;
mysql> CREATE USER `flask-docker`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON flask_docker.* TO 'flask-docker'@'localhost';
mysql> exit
Bye
$ docker exec -it flaskdocker_web_1 python /usr/src/app/manage.py createdb
# rest of traceback
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, u"Access denied for user 'flask-docker'@'flaskdocker_web_1.flaskdocker_default' (using password: YES)")
```

Here is the repo https://github.com/Amertz08/flask-docker

It looks like the SqlAlchemy engine is not looking at the right container. `'flask-docker'@'flaskdocker_web_1.flaskdocker_default'` is what shows up in the error.

Maybe I am not understanding it right but I linked `mysql:mysql` in my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
web:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/static
    expose:
      - "5000"
    environment:
      FLASK_CONFIG: 'production'
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    command: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

Then in my config object in `config.py` I have the following...

```
MYSQL_USER = 'flask-docker'
MYSQL_PASS = 'pass'
MYSQL_HOST = 'mysql'
MYSQL_DB = 'flask_docker'
# Database info
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://{usr}:{passwd}@{host}/{db}'.format(
    usr=MYSQL_USER, passwd=MYSQL_PASS, host=MYSQL_HOST, db=MYSQL_DB
)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've linked the container with the name `mysql`. You don't need to refer to it as `flask_docker`. Also, you can just say `mysql` instead of `mysql:mysql`. The latter form is only needed when you map a container under a different name (e.g., `mysql:flask_docker`).

Comment: valid point. Changed thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem there:

`mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON flask_docker.* TO 'flask-docker'@'localhost';`
You grant privileges for **localhost** user

But you use mysql as `flask-docker'@'flaskdocker_web_1.flaskdocker_default` user.

To solve this grant user privileges for flask-docker'@'**flaskdocker_web_1.flaskdocker_default** user

Comment: This appears to fix the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another solution here as I had a difficult time with this problem. In order for me to get access to the database from Flask I used `mysql-connector` (can be installed via `pip install mysql-connector`), entered the mysql shell and ran the following code `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';`

I then connected to mysql using the following config:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .db import db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://root:foo@127.0.0.1:3306/bar_db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I'm still not quite sure why this work around was needed as I've never knowingly used it before in any other Python application however it does appear to work with libmysqlclient.

src: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html